# $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+10}{n}=2$ via $\epsilon - N$

Tags: real-analysis

This should be trivial for me, but I have forgotten how to do these problems over the last 2 years. I can obviously 'prove' it using calculus methods, but I want to do it via an $\epsilon - N$ argument.

How do I go about doing this?

$$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+10}{n}=2$$

---

From what I can recall I want to look at:

$$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N\in \Bbb Z|n\geq N \implies |A_n-l|\lt \epsilon$$

Now I know what I want is some $N(\epsilon, l)$, but I cannot seem to wrap my mind around the actual proof.

---

Perhaps I set $\frac{2N+10}{N} - 2\lt \epsilon$, find when this is true, and then use the original argument with $n\geq N$, but I cannot seem to get it. Thanks

Comment: why use $\epsilon- N$... just split it as $lim 2+10/n$ ..

Comment: @SrinivasK This is due to starting a course in functional analysis, and being told I will need to touch up on these methods prior to working on cauchy sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

$$\tag{*}\left|\frac{2n + 10}{n} - 2\right| = \left|2 + \frac{10}{n} - 2\right| = \frac{10}{n},$$

given $\epsilon > 0$, setting $N > 10/\epsilon$ will make the left hand side of $(*)$ less than $\epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

Comment: Thank you, that does it. So really we are just setting $\frac{2N+10}{N}-2\lt \epsilon$ and solving for $N$ so we have $\frac{10}{\epsilon}\lt N$ and subbing in where we can see $\frac{10}{n}\leq \frac{10}{N}=\frac{10}{\frac{10}{\epsilon}}= \epsilon$

Comment: @FriendlyTower that's basically it.

Comment: $\text{Basically }\implies\text{ Something went wrong}\quad$ Is some part of above not acceptably rigorous? (Ignoring the short form)

Comment: Or you are saying, I need not construct it that way, but that way is acceptable. The practice is more about finding that example?

Comment: @FriendlyTower well, not really. You just need to mention that $n \ge N$ after doing the inequalities.

Comment: Good point, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{2n+10\over n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{2+10/n}$$

by multiplying numerator and denominator by $1/n$.

Comment: I wanted to use $\epsilon -N$, but the other answers have covered this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the limit is $2$, you form the difference $$\left|\frac{2n+10}{n}-2\right|= \left|\frac{10}{n}\right| $$Thus, for all $\epsilon >0$,  $$\left|\frac{2n+10}{n}-2\right| <\epsilon$$whenever $n>N \ge \frac{10}{\epsilon}$

Comment: Good answer. I can't upvote due to reputation unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunately Kobe beat you(in time) ;)